# "unfortunately the process com.google.process.gapps has stopped" even after hard reset

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have a Blu Life 8 (Kitkat) phone and was getting some annoyng messages: "com.google.process.gapps has stopped", i tried to hard reset it to see if the problem was gone, but even after reset i could not get the message to disappear, and now i can't even go after the initial setup process cause it crashes every 0.1 seconds showing this error.
Is there  way to fully restore the default settings or something like that? How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for your case is to fully flash your phone. I've been searching around for Android 4.4 firmware for your phone, but I couldn't find any, just for Android 4.2.2. But there is no problem flashing with it. Follow these steps and get your phone working again.

**Flashing FW:**

1. Unpack SP-FlashTool, and run `Flash_tool.exe`
2. Select `MT6592_Android_scatter.txt` from `Firmware` folder
3. Wait for file to be added into Flash Tool
4. Choose Option -> USB Model, click USB Model
5. Choose Option -> DA DownLoad All->Speed -> High Speed, click High Speed
6. Turn off your phone, remove the battery then put it back after few seconds (and don't turn on the phone).
7. "Press F9 (hit Download button)" OR "if upgrade ROM Firmware->Upgrade "
8. Connect your phone into the computer via USB data cable.
9. The process will start and a red progress bar will appear after color purple, yellow.
10. And green circles display

Finish!

Note: Flashing tutorial credits goes to [Needrom.com](http://needrom.com/).

**Download:**

- SP FlashTool: [HERE](http://d-h.st/w6v)
- BLU_ROM_L280a: [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0l32kyuaasq3hn2/AAAXjQguX_kGaN2fOeIBfwv5a?dl=0)
- BLU_ROM_L280i: [HERE](https://mega.nz/#!YldWzQaA!0CDwKfHe_mFkI7Iyk0Jg1lpqE43VP2m-gfvnclvBtnM)